# Using alltray in Kubuntu 16.04: "ERROR get class hints"

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, system-tray

I'm trying to use `alltray` in Kubuntu 16.04, mainly to get Spotify into the tray. But however I start alltray, it only exits with the message "ERROR get classhints". I have tried both `alltray`, `alltray spotify`, `alltray dolphin`, and a number of other options.

Is it possible to use alltray in Kubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved by building from source...

1. download

> wget
>   https://launchpad.net/alltray/trunk/0.7.5.1dev/+download/alltray-0.7.5.1dev.tar.gz
>
> or
>
> wget https://github.com/mbt/alltray/archive/v0.7.5.1dev.zip

```
tar -xvf v0.7.5.1dev.zip
cd alltray*
./configure
make
cd src
./alltray
```

to install rung make install